# Make name uppercase with multiple capital letters

Tags: javascript, regex, capitalization

Basically, I'd like to do the following:

```
    McDonald => McDONALD
    McDowell => McDOWELL
    McIntosh => McINTOSH
    etc.
```

I'm also looking into things like iPhone => iPHONE, but I'm probably just going to use a set list for that. However, the names change regularly, and it would be an inconvenience to keep a running list.

Is it possible to do this? I was looking at regex, but I couldn't think of a way to do it without lookbehind (I'm using JavaScript).

Comment: By the look of it you don't have a clear defined pattern for every case (McDonald [2 first letter], iPhone [1 letter]), so I would go for a list of prefixes, then substring that prefix from the word then make everything else uppercase join then two!

Comment: @Xufox I'm working in Javascript, which doesn't have lookbehind

Comment: In javascrit you can't do this kind of replacing with regex.

Comment: This seems like an incredibly strange thing to do. If you're not going to uppercase the `c` in `Mc`, why do you uppercase everything after it?

Comment: It's for scripting (a teleprompter), where everything is in all caps (for readability reasons). Although it isn't bad to have a name in all caps (when one should be lowercase), there are frequent occasions on which this would be useful (since the town it's for has two capitals)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var convertName = function(name){
  var pattern=/^(.*?[a-z][A-Z])(.*)$/g;
  if(pattern.test(name)){
    return name.replace(pattern,function(t,a,b){
      return a+b.toUpperCase();
    });
  }
  else{
    return name.toUpperCase();
  }
};
```

It basically looks for the first upper-case letter after the first lower-case letter, separates that first part from the rest and makes the rest upper-case. This only happens, if such a pattern is found. Otherwise it simply returns the name in upper-case.

### Usage

```
convertName('McDonald'); // McDONALD
convertName('McDowell'); // McDOWELL
convertName('McIntosh'); // McINTOSH
convertName('iPhone'); // iPHONE
convertName('Smith'); // SMITH
```

### Replacing multiple instances

The simplest way is by matching every group of letters and putting that into the function. You can use:

```
"Word, test, “words”, McIntosh is a name, just like Herbert-McIntosh. So much upper-case.".replace(/(\w+)/g,function(t,w){
  return convertName(w);
});
// "WORD, TEST, “WORDS”, McINTOSH IS A NAME, JUST LIKE HERBERT-McINTOSH. SO MUCH UPPER-CASE."
//                                        Prefix after a dash ^^^
```

Comment: If there's no `McX` at the beginning, I think he wants to uppercase the whole thing. So `Smith` should become `SMITH`.

Comment: @Barmar then why he wants this `iPhone => iPHONE` ?

Comment: he said that's a special case

Comment: This is for a TelePrompTer, so normal text is uppercase. He's only using mixed case for prefixes like `i` and `Mc`.

Comment: This answer is definitely the best! I'm just searching for a way to implement this to loop through every word to check it (unless there's a way to do this with regex, which I don't think there is)

(and yes, I would like Smith to go to SMITH)

Comment: @user2718801 What is a “word” in your case? If someone’s name is “Herbert-McIntosh” should it become “HERBERT-MCINTOSH” (as one word) or “HERBERT-McINTOSH” (as two words)?

Comment: For this purpose, a word is anything delimited by a space (so the latter of the two). However, a case like this will likely never show up (and if it does, so be it), so it doesn't much matter.

Comment: Ok, I added another section for replacing multiple instances.

Comment: That's an excellent solution! Much simpler than what I was trying to do (if the pattern is found, then break by newline, check each for the pattern again, then concatenate multiple times).

This got implemented smoothly. I can't think of anything wrong (or further additions), so I'm happy to say the problem has been solved completely!

Thanks a ton @Xufox

Comment: No problem! The alternative form “HERBERT-MCINTOSH” can’t be easily done, anyway, as the function will convert it to “Herbert-McINTOSH” because, well… it follows the pattern…

Comment: That's what I prefer anyway, I just didn't know if it would match by default